# Is it possible to know name of continent/country if we know timezone ID?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to know the name of continent/country provided timezone id?
     For e.g.

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));

I wanted answer as north america/america. 

System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));

I wanted answer as asia/india.

i am not getting the desired output.

The reason of asking question :: I am storing in my database on server the timezone(PDT,GMT+05:30) as given by the mobile    
device.Now i need to perform analytics , that my app was  accessed from which continent/country.
```

Help is appreciated...

Comment: Ok, what if you have GMT+1, thats a random bit of europe and africa. Not to mention Antarctica.

Comment: So which continent or country should be returned for GMT+01:00 ?

Answer (score 5):

No. Timezones cut vertically over the globe and there are many countries which share the same timezone.

For example, India is southwest of China, so the answer "China" would be equally correct for some timezones.

See this web site for a map of timezones and which countries they apply to: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/

Comment: so it is not possible to get the desired output as suggested by me.?

Comment: Not from `GMT+05:30`. It is used in India and Nepal.

Comment: from codes like PST,IST,BST these are country specific codes... now is it possible

Comment: Sometimes. The codes mentioned by Zavior are pretty specific. There are other codes (http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/) which are also specific but not all of them. My feeling is that some of them are pretty good but `PST` can be two different time zones (Pacific or Pitcairn Standard Time). But in general, time zones are really not suitable for geolocation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work it out backwards, this might be of some help...
Some of the TimeZones include a bit of the info you are looking for, for example, try:

```
 for (String s : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
            System.out.println(s);
 }
```

Output is as follows..

```
...
Europe/Amsterdam
Europe/Andorra
Europe/Belgrade
Europe/Berlin
Europe/Bratislava
Europe/Brussels
Europe/Budapest
Europe/Copenhagen
Europe/Gibraltar
Europe/Ljubljana
Europe/Luxembourg
Europe/Madrid
Europe/Malta
Europe/Monaco
Europe/Oslo
Europe/Paris
...
```

This you could use to grab the TimeZones and check the info they have, you might be able to get what you want, albeit with a lot of work.

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Outputs

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Amsterdam",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=180,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Amsterdam,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

Using the offset, you can work out the relation to UTC time. Even in a simple case where you don't consider daylight savings etc, this is very complex, tricky and time consuming. Possible, I'd say.